# unable to put deserialized json into gridview

Tags: c#, json

Gridview unable to get json data due to invalid data type. From what i understand it needs a List<> data source. How do i make my data populate my gridview?

The received JSON from the api

```
{"BTC":{"SGD":4864.11,"USD":3617.33,"EUR":3162.71}}
```

...

```
public class BTC
{
    public double SGD { get; set; }
    public double USD { get; set; }
    public double EUR { get; set; }
}

public class CryptoPrice
{
    public BTC BTC { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=SGD,USD,EUR&api_key=<secret_key>");
var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
     JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
     string resString = sr.ReadToEnd();
     CryptoPrice list = json.Deserialize<CryptoPrice>(resString);

     GridView1.DataSource = list.BTC;
     GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not 100% sure but your data source is not a list. As you can see in your code you’re deserializing returned Json to only one instance of `CryptoPrice` type. Try deserializing it to `List<CryptoPrice>` and assign it as data source to your grid view.